# Wild-card style C preprocessor trick

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, wildcard

I have a lot of compilation flags that configure my program for different customers.
For instance: `MODE_A_1`, `MODE_A_2`, `MODE_B_1`, ... `MODE_AB_54`, ...

I would really like some preprocessor trick that would allow me to to such pseudo code:

```
#ifdef MODE_A_.*
```

Instead of having to type every MODE_A_.. occurrences:

```
#if defined(MODE_A_1) && defined(MODE_A_2) && ...
```

It would be even cooler if regexes could be applied.

Comment: Enhance the build to define `MODE_A` if any of the `MODE_A_` flags need to be defined. This should be simple for any modern build system.

Comment: Issue is that I have not only 2 parameters( letter and digit) but a lot more. I would have to write down all the combinatorics

Comment: No, the issue is that you're mixing feature flags and targets. You just need the build system (or a header somewhere) to enable a list of actual feature flags based on the target. Then all your conditionals can depend on a single relevant feature flag.

Comment: @Useless that's what Boost uses. I think Windows.h also does it that way

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going by the macro name, why not make the macro name a bit pattern denoting features.  For example

```
#define FEAT_VCORNERS        0x01
#define FEAT_VPANEL          0x02
#define FEAT_DOOR_FULL_PANEL 0x04
```

OK so it limits you to 32 individual features - that is not many but it may be enough

Then for each customer you define what features they have.  It doesn't matter if the pattern is repeated

```
#define CUST_A (FEAT_VCORNERS)
#define CUST_B (FEAT_VCORNERS)
#define CUST_C (FEAT_VPANEL | FEAT_DOOR_FULL_PANEL)
#define CUST_D (FEAT_VCORNERS | FEAT_VPANEL)
```

In the build input you could define -DCUST=CUST_D.  In the code, you just need to test

```
#if CUST & FEAT_VCORNERS
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have a lot of compilation flags that configure my program for different customers. For instance: `MODE_A_1`, `MODE_A_2`, `MODE_B_1`, ... `MODE_AB_54`, ...

But "MODE_A_1" is not a customer. You're confusing two completely different things at a very basic level.

If you want a list of features you can enable/disable independently for different customers, use something like

```
#if defined(CUSTOMER_GUILLAUME)

#define ENABLE_FEATURE_A
#define ENABLE_FEATURE_1

#elif defined(CUSTOMER_USELESS)

#define ENABLE_FEATURE_B
#define ENABLE_FEATURE_2

// ...

#endif
```

Then instead of

```
#if defined(MODE_A_1) && defined(MODE_A_2) && ...
```

you just use

```
#if defined(ENABLE_FEATURE_A)
```

Note that I'm just using on/off feature flags. You *can* set them to say integer version numbers if you need finer control such as `#if (FEATURE_C_VERSION > 123)` ...